# Keep Android 11 IME active in background

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, ime, soft-input-panel

I developed a IME for Android that connects on bluetooth device and receive reading from it but still expose a conventional software keyboard. The problem is that if I hide the keyboard, the bluetooth device disconnects.

I made it reconnect automatically when the keyboard is displayed again. But I what want is that even if keyboard is hidden my device still able to send data to app. This is possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind folks, is my reconnecting routine that is totally idiot! I made the same function to connect and reconnect, so when you hide the keyboard it invokes the reconnect function and disconnects the device... OH MY!